# how safely SUM TIME fields where the sum will likely overflow the 35 days limit?

Tags: mysql, time, overflow

Mysql [`TIME` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) as a maximum of 35 days

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'

The same limit applies to the result of [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec).

So how can I safely SUM TIME type fields in contexts where the sum will likely overflow the 35 days limit?

Comment: You can't, At least without converting it to a numerical type with a decent range first. But once you are over the limt of those +/- 839 days, there is no way back to a `TIME` until you are back within limits ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you may need summarize times. But you always can convert it to seconds and summarize seconds as longint.

```
select sum(TIME_TO_SEC(time_column)) as sumtime from table
```

Comment: "*why you may need summarize times*" because according to the docs, the `TIME` type is not only used to represent the time of the day, but also for timespans ...